# Azure: How to correctly use a PHP webjob to make changes to SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, azure, azure-webjobs, webjob

**GOAL**: To use a PHP webjob to connect and alter SQL database table in Azure.

I'm trying to upload a `.zip` file containing a `.php` and a `.json` file to the webjobs settings inside of an app service I have running on Azure.

I believe there's something wrong with the way I'm coding the PDO-SQL connection inside of the PHP file, when I upload the webjob as a `.zip` into webjobs, the Status is always "Pending Restart".

Here's what I have in my `.php` file:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO ( "sqlsrv:server = mydb.database.windows.net,1433; Database = myappservices");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  print( "Error connecting to SQL Server." );
}
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "myappservices");
$serverName = "mydb.database.windows.net,1433";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
  $stf = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyTable
                        VALUES ('boom', 1, 2);");
  $stf->execute();
}

?>
```

Then my `.json` file is just a scheduler:

```
{
    "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
}
```

These are the only two files in my `.zip` file I'm uploading.

To explain the PHP code, I'm trying to connect via windows authentication (no need for user/pass). Maybe I'm doing this wrong too.

Anyone have any ways to do this? I would really appreciate giving a step by step or suggestions as to how to change my code to get this webjob to actually run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this **job.php**:

```or-tag-here
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    // DON'T HARDCODE CREDENTIALS, pull from Application Settings.
    // In Azure App Service, Application Settings are exposed as
    // environment variables.
    //
    // i.e. $db_user = getenv("DB_USER");
    //
    $conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server = poqfsXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;
                     Database = MobileApp_db",
                     "Username", "P@ssw0rd");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server: " + $e);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from todoitems");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}

unset($conn);
unset($stmt);

?>
```

Expected output:
(You can test in Kudu: *https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole*)

```
d:\home\site\tests> "d:\program files (x86)\php\v5.6\php.exe" job.php

Array
(
    [Id] => d4657cff-09a2-4a8a-b1d2-462c2c42a9f0
    [0] => d4657cff-09a2-4a8a-b1d2-462c2c42a9f0
    [Text] => From Azure SQL
    [1] => From Azure SQL
    [Complete] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [Version] => 0000000000001825
    [3] => 0000000000001825
    [CreatedAt] => 2016-06-17 10:11:17.1167267 +00:00
    [4] => 2016-06-17 10:11:17.1167267 +00:00
    [UpdatedAt] => 2016-06-17 10:11:17.1167267 +00:00
    [5] => 2016-06-17 10:11:17.1167267 +00:00
    [Deleted] => 0
    [6] => 0
)
Array
(
    ...
)
...
```

> To explain the PHP code, I'm trying to connect via windows authentication (no need for user/pass). Maybe I'm doing this wrong too.

While Azure SQL does support Windows Authentication, i'm not exactly sure what you mean by "no need for user/pass". Windows Authentication means **"take the credentials of whomever this process is running as and attempt authentication against the SQL server"**. Since you're running your Webjob as a random user provided by the sandbox, Windows Authentication doesn't make much sense.

From Kudu's Process Explorer:

[image: Process Explorer]

Here's one valid scenario for Windows Authentication with Azure SQL:

You have an on-prem hosted application that uses Active Directory to authenticate to your on-prem SQL Server. You have a requirement to move to Azure SQL. You do not have the option to change the authentication method for SQL. So you *dirsync* your directory to Azure AD and use Windows Authentication to connect to Azure SQL.

More on Windows Authentication in Azure SQL:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer, I've got one more question if you're open to solving it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430631/azure-php-sql-dbo-webjob-not-working-why-does-it-get-thrown-on-query-execute